# AngularJs Accessing Elements of an Array Within an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

How do you access the content of an array within an array with `ng-repeat`?

My first array is called `products` and the one within that is called `jobs`. I am trying to access the data in the `jobs` array while still having angular know that I am accessing a specific section.

I am trying

```
ng-repeat="job in products.jobs"
```

but it is not working, how should i tackle this instead?

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would probably help you get better answers. Thanks!

Comment: I would but it said I have to have 10 points to be able to post pictures and links!

Comment: Edit your code in *as code*: plain text, not a screenshot of your IDE window, and not a link to some external code-hosting site. Code, right here.